# Unable to click a particular element in selenium(using python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Below is the tried code

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://flipkart.com")

input2_css_locator = "input[name='q']"
cross_button = "//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']"
button4_xpath_locator = "//button"
product_button = "//div[@class='_3wU53n']"



# Assign elements
input2_element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(input2_css_locator)
button4_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(button4_xpath_locator)
cross_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(cross_button)
product_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(product_button)



# browser.switchTo().alert().dismiss()
#Manipulate elements

cross_element.click()

input2_element.send_keys("mobile")
button4_element.click()

product_button.click()
# browser.quit()
```

It will not work for sure as this will point to 2 classes instead of 1.

I just tried to modify same code in line no 18.

```
product_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(product_button).[0].innerText
```

error in this case:

**product_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(product_button).[0].innerText
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I tried to change the same in line 10 also, but that is also not working.

I just want to click the first link(or any link whichever user wants), Can you help me where I am making mistake and with the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra dot`(.)` before `[0]`. It should be

```
product_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(product_button)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case getting the below error:      **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'innerText''**

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
`productElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath(BUTTON_NAME)[0]`

Comment: Thanks , but getting the below error   **selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='_3wU53n']"}**